# Open source or free online dashboard

Tags: gratis, postgresql, dashboard

I am planning a small project which involves the use of online dashboards but I'm having trouble finding nice free ones.
By nice I mean, performant, appealing to the eye and flexible (I know I ask for too much and for it to be free, but I believe there has to be something out there.)

So far I have found this one which provides a free solution if self-hosted: https://redash.io/. There is nothing wrong with redash, I just want to know additional alternatives and not just stick to the first one I found.

The main idea of the dashboard solution I'm looking for is to be able to connect to a Postgresql database and display graphs/charts based on data in it.
It doesn't need to have scheduling or query storage, just something that can read data and transform it into graphs or tables I can then display online.

Comment: A dashboard for what? What do you need it for exactly, which features does it need?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation, I added an edit to complete this information

Comment: Adding a short list of what is wrong with solution you have found may also help people recommend you something else. [Here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/31218/8327) you have a question similar to yours and an example of "what is wrong" that helps to narrow the search / suggestion list.

Comment: just added another edit, nothing is wrong, i just dont want to stick to the first solution i found

Answer (score 4):

[Syncfusion Dashboard Platform](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/dashboard) is an option to consider.

Dashboards need to be designed using the Dashboard Designer (windows application) and published using the Dashboard Server (web application). Self hosted is the only option for now.

[image: Syncfusion Dashboard]

The dashboard platform and more are available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify. The licensing cost is not expensive even otherwise. Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Subrion (https://subrion.org/).  Easy to install, uses just php and mysql, can be installed with Softaculous.  Not sure if it work with Postgre as I only installed yesterday and so am still discovering.

Comment: were you able to verify that it did/didnt work with postgres?

Comment: @nr_aus no I didn't try I was just responding to that part of the OP's question.